# How to make a letter input and float input in a same statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, netbeans

Create program segments that will the user if he wants to accept an evaluation score or an evaluation letter of a faculty. Print the name of the faculty and the remarks obtained. Remarks (rem) are based on the following criteria: (remarks.java)

```
SCORE/LETTER        REMARKS
4.50-5.00 or A          Outstanding
4.00-4.49 or B          Very Satisfactory
3.50-3.99 or C          Satisfactory
3.00-3.49 or D          Needs Improvement
2.99    below or E          Poor
```

Kindly help me how to input letter choices to add in if else statement.

As of now, this is my program:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

String n;
float score;


System.out.println("Enter Faculty's Name:");
n=in.nextLine(); //asking the user to incode his/her name

System.out.println("Enter score:");
score=in.nextFloat(); //asking the user to incode score


if ( score >=4.50  )//  4.50 to 5.00
    System.out.println("Remark: Outstanding");

else if(score>=4.00)// 4.00 to 4.49
    System.out.println("Remark: Very Satisfactory");

else if(score>=3.50)// 3.50 to 3.99
    System.out.println("Remark: Satisfactory");

else if(score>=3.00)//3.00 to 3.49
    System.out.println("Remark: Needs Improvement");

else
    System.out.println("Remark: Poor");
```

Comment: Accept the input as string, and then use String.equals() method on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    String n, score;

    System.out.println("Enter Faculty's Name:");
    n=in.nextLine(); //asking the user to incode his/her name

    System.out.println("Enter score:");
    score=in.nextLine(); //asking the user to incode score

    if ("ABCDE".contains(score.toUpperCase())) {
        if (score.equalsIgnoreCase("a"))//  4.50 to 5.00
            System.out.println("Remark: Outstanding");

        else if(score.equalsIgnoreCase("b"))// 4.00 to 4.49
            System.out.println("Remark: Very Satisfactory");

        else if(score.equalsIgnoreCase("c"))// 3.50 to 3.99
            System.out.println("Remark: Satisfactory");

        else if(score.equalsIgnoreCase("d"))//3.00 to 3.49
            System.out.println("Remark: Needs Improvement");

        else
            System.out.println("Remark: Poor");

    } else {
        if (Float.valueOf(score) >=4.50)//  4.50 to 5.00
        System.out.println("Remark: Outstanding");

        else if(Float.parseFloat(score) >=4.00 )// 4.00 to 4.49
            System.out.println("Remark: Very Satisfactory");

        else if(Float.parseFloat(score) >=3.50 )// 3.50 to 3.99
            System.out.println("Remark: Satisfactory");

        else if(Float.parseFloat(score) >=3.00 )//3.00 to 3.49
            System.out.println("Remark: Needs Improvement");

        else
            System.out.println("Remark: Poor");            
    }
```